# Error in importing modules from a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, environment-variables, python-import, virtual

I created a virtual environment through [Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), and I had to install the NumPy library. But when I try to import it in the shell, it tells me *"No module named 'NumPy'"*.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
numpy = "*"
requests = "==2.18.1"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
python_full_version = "3.10.0"`
```

#### Terminal session

```
cd C:\Users\AMMAR\Desktop
cd project-1
pipenv shell
```

Output:

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows
```

```
python3
```

Output:

```
Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

#### Requests library trial

I tried to install the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library and when I import it into the shell, it gives me the same message:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't in the virtual environment when you run the `import` statement, or when you use `pip install [moduleName]`.

I ran into this issue too, so I know what to do.

Create your virtual environment, and then make sure your terminal prompt shows the location of it.  Then run `[environmentName]\Scripts\Activate` (provided you are using Windows).  Now you can run `pip install [moduleName]` to install the modules you need.